# How to transfer data using more than one form in one page?

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I want to transfer different data by one click from one list to a table.

```
@foreach($books as $book)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $book->identification }}</td>
    <td>{{ $book->userid }}</td>
    <td>{{ $book->lentdate }}</td>
    <td>{{ $book->lentby}}</td>
    <td> 
        <a href="{{ action('BookController@edit', $book->id) }}" class="btn btn-default"> Edit</a>&emsp;
        <a href="{{ action('BookController@show', $book->id) }}" class="btn btn-default"> View</a> &emsp;
        <a href="{{ action('BookController@receive', $book->id) }}" class="btn btn-default"> Return</a>&emsp;
        <a href="{{ action('BookController@destroy', $book->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger"> Delete</a> &emsp;
        <a href="{{ action('BookController@lost', $book->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger"> lost</a> 

        <form  action="{{ action('BooklateController@store' ) }}" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="ident"  id="id" value='{{ $book->id }}'>
        <input type="hidden" name="day"  id="day" value='{{ $book->lentdat }}'>
        <input type="hidden" name="user"  id="user" value='{{ $book->userid}}'>      
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value=" day late" >
    </td>
</tr>                
@endforeach
```

Here is some of view and I want to send different data every time I submit.

It is however only sending the data of the last row.

My route:

```
Route::post('createbooklate','BooklateController@store');
```

My controller:

```
public function store(request $request)
{
    booklatefee::create(['book'=>$request->input('id'),
                'day'=>$request->input('day'),
                'payer'=>$request->input('user') ]);

    return Redirect::action('BookController@index');
}
```

Comment: Closing your form could help. Moreover you dont need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` because you have no file inside your form.

Comment: it still send the last data

Comment: Just to be sure, can you update your post with the modifications please ?

Comment: Thank you closing the form solve it